# Use @PathParam(javax.websocket.server.PathParam) in WebSocketConfigurer for Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, websocket, java-websocket

I have created a spring boot application in which I want to use Web Sockets. When I am using it without parameters its working fine. Below is the code without the parameters

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer  {
    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(new ABC(), "/getABC").setAllowedOrigins("*");
        registry.addHandler(new XYZ(), "/getXYZ").setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

But now I need to pass a parameter to it using @PathParam. I am not able to use it in this configuration like

```
registry.addHandler(new XYZ(), "/getXYZ{someId}").setAllowedOrigins("*");
```

My Handler code:

```
public class XYZ extends TextWebSocketHandler {

        static List<WebSocketSession> sessions = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        String someId;

        public XYZ() {
        }

        public XYZ(@PathParam(value = "someId") String someId) {
            this.someId= someId;
        }

        @Override
        public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {
            // the messages will be broadcasted to all users.
            sessions.add(session);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you found a solution? I'm stuck at the same point.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some problem with the syntax, try using

```
public XYZ(@PathParam("someId") String someId)
```

Comment: This constructor is already present in the Handler. How to pass this from WebSocketConfig is the question in case of spring boot. This will work fine when we use @ServerEndpoint for registrying the Handler.